# getting no such element exception

Tags: css, xpath

i am getting error as element cannot be found when executing code for one of the test application. I have written code to locate element using css and xpath,but still getting same issue. can any one help?

code :

```
public static WebDriver driver;

    public static void setUp() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "Resources\\IEDriverServer.exe"); 
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\selenium\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");   

        driver.get("http://demo.actitime.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("user");

        driver.findElement(By.name("pwd")).sendKeys("user");

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#loginButton > div")).click();

        //Wait<WebDriver> wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("logoutLink")));

        //String parentWindow= driver.getWindowHandle();

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.popup_menu_icon.support_icon > div.popup_menu_arrow")).click();

//driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('topnav')/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td[5]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]/x:div/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td/x:div/x:div[2]/x:div/x:div[1]/x:div[2]")).click();


        driver.findElement(By.linkText("User Guide")).click();
    }

    public static void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        setUp();

        tearDown();


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the error message to your question please?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == div.popup_menu_icon.support_icon > div.popup_menu_arrow (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 834 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: Quick search from dev. tools on http://demo.actitime.com/ shows that there is no "popup" something on this page (neither class nor id, etc.)

Comment: i was trying to click the help icon on the top right corner once login in to application. i cannot able to click "help"icon as i am getting that error

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the Login Button it takes the browser a couple of seconds to send your request and return/render the response page, But in your code, You're trying to click the Help button right after clicking the login button(the help button isn't displayed yet), Which won't find the element you're looking for in the current page, because you're still on the login page.

So you need to wait till the page after the login is rendered and then you can select and click on whatever you want.

To wait for the element to be clickable use this code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(cssSelector("div.popup_menu_icon.support_icon > div.popup_menu_arrow")));
```

**EDIT:**

It seems that you're using the wrong css selector. Try this one:

```
cssSelector("div.popup_menu_button.popup_menu_button_support")
```

Comment: hey, i tried as per your info.. added external wait command . but i am still getting error that element not found. below is the error info.

Comment: hey, i tried as per your info.. added external wait command . but i am still getting error that element not found. below is the error info.Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: div.popup_menu_icon.support_icon > div.popup_menu_arrow (tried for 50 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
 at

Comment: issue got fixed and i can able to select the user guide. changed css selector as per the below command.String parentWindow= driver.getWindowHandle();
  
  
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.popup_menu_icon.support_icon"))).click();